# How to edit what an entry widget displays

Tags: python

How would I change what is in the E1 (entry widget's variable name) when a button is pressed to activate this code (I just wanna edit the display from this function if possible):

```
def remove_one():
    text = str(E1.get())
    for i in '1':
        text = text.replace(i, "")
    return text
```

the entry would only be taking numbers, so I would want this function to change "121314151617181910" to "234567890"

This is my entry widget:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
E1 = Tkinter.Entry(root)
assert isinstance(E1, object)
E1.grid(column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='E')
```

Comment: `print "121314151617181910".replace("1", "")`

Comment: I want to update the E1 variable, not print it out.

Comment: the point was showing you that you don't need a loop to replace all the 1's - you can do it in one `replace`.

Comment: oh, well I didn't realize that, I'll keep that in mind next time, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`delete()` and `insert()` methods](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

```
def remove_one():
    text = E1.get().replace('1', "")
    E1.delete(0, END)
    E1.insert(0, text)
```

Comment: As long as I use `from Tkconstants import END` and `def remove_one():
    text = E1.get().replace('1', "")
    E1.delete(0, END)
    E1.insert(0, text)` it works great, thanks.

Comment: @Sergio - Yes, I'm sorry, `END` is one of the available constants in Tkinter. You could also use `Tkinter.END` or simply the string `'end'`.